# How to redirect www to non-www and http to https using nginx and cloudflare?

Tags: ssl, nginx, seo, server, cloudflare

I am using the following to redirect all users to `https` and to `non-www`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log rt_cache;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

    root "/usr/share/nginx/app/public";
    index index.php index.htm index.html;

    charset utf-8;

    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    include hhvm.conf;

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Note: I am also using CloudFlare.

When I visit `example.com`, I am redirected to `https://example.com`.  Great.

But `www.example.com` redirects to `https://www.example.com` and the site does not load.

Visiting `https://example.com` works fine.

Is this a server configuration problem or a CloudFlare problem?  How can it be fixed?

Comment: Your configuration looks good, no problem from nginx for sure. You might have done something buggy in CloudFlare.

Comment: Also, better add redirect condition on CloudFlare to redirect https://www.example.com to https://example.com. Here is how : https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-How-do-I-perform-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-CloudFlare-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to add a DNS A record to allow `www` to point to my server's IP address.  Then, nginx could redirect without a problem.